# How to create an onClick event on a form submit button

Tags: python, django, django-forms, form-submit

I am trying to create an onClick event in my Django view. The idea is that when the user clicks "submit" on each page a survey form that the value of a jQuery slider `slider_value` gets inserted into a list `slider_DV_values`.

However my below attempt the `if self.request.POST.get('submit'):` simply checks to see if there is a 'submit' in the `self.request.POST.get` and therefore is triggered each time. I only want it added after the user has clicked submit.

How do I create an onClick event so that the below `slider_value` only gets added to the `slider_DV_values` when the user clicks submit on the form page

**views.py**

```
if step == 5:                       
    if self.request.POST.get('submit'):                              
        slider_value = self.request.POST.get('slider_value')
        slider_DV_values.insert(step - 5, slider_value)                    
        print 'This is the slide value', slider_value
```

**form.html**

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="{% trans "submit" %}"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: I've read your question about five times and it's unreal to understand what do you want) but from title of your question maybe this helps http://api.jquery.com/submit/ :)

Comment: That would be almost exactly what i want, except I need to do it in Python/Django